# showmessagedialog warning and information message types in one frame

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` is able to get only one messagetype. How can i achieve that show **WARNING_MESSAGE** and **INFORMATION_MESSAGE** same one dialog with `JOptionPane` ?

Comment: Can you specify how a `JOptionPane` would look like that's a `WARNING_MESSAG` and an `INFORMATION_MESSAGE` at the same time? You can check the source of `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object)` for reusable snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class OptionPaneTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new OptionPaneTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 10));
        JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel("Here is my info message");
        infoLabel.setIconTextGap(10);
        infoLabel.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        p.add(infoLabel);
        JLabel warnLabel = new JLabel("Here is my warning message");
        warnLabel.setIconTextGap(10);
        warnLabel.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"));
        p.add(warnLabel);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p, "Here is my info and warn message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I highlighted :) Thanks for your kind reply

Comment: @ayciceksamet glad to help you. If possible, please mark this answer as "best answer".